# Update Shopify cart with ajax without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify

I am changing a users Shopify shopping cart with Ajax, the cart is being changed successfully but in order to display the updated cart the user has to refresh the page. I want to display the cart changes WITHOUT a refresh.

I'm using the ajax api just fine, and I can add and remove items with:

```
Shopify.addItem();
Shopify.removeItem();
```

Those work great, but they require the user to reload the page to see the new/changed items in their cart. Do you know of a way to display the updated cart WITHOUT a page reload?

So everyone has the complete picture, here is my code:

```
function poll(products) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/apps/proxy",
    data: {products: products},
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    complete: setTimeout(function() 
      {cartAdd(); poll(products)}, 15000),
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(incoming_key, incoming_value){
        Shopify.getCart(function(cart){
          $.each(cart.items, function(cart_key, cart_value){
            if(cart_value.variant_id == incoming_value.id_to_remove){                 
              Shopify.addItem(incoming_value.variant_id, incoming_value.quantity);
              Shopify.removeItem(incoming_value.id_to_remove);
              console.log("some reason the incoming id is null or maybe not " + incoming_value.variant_id );
            }
            else if(cart_value.variant_id == incoming_value.variant_id && cart_value.quantity != incoming_value.quantity){
              Shopify.changeItem(cart_value.variant_id, incoming_value.quantity);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    },
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an ajax call to the cart page `/cart`, get the required elements and replace them on the current page.

Add the code for the above after the first `$.each` function.

Comment: This is only working for 1 theme. If my app is installed on multiple themes, how can I replace the elements with different ids and classes?

Comment: @BennyChan themes generally have a fixed class and id for the side cart. AFAIK, the apps are expected to work on Shopify's default themes. If you have custom theme with custom classes/ids, there isn't much you can do.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the shopify ajax cart, after insert or update call the GET action:
[using-ajax-api#get-cart](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#get-cart)